# Change Rectangle Position Sketchflow Blend

Tags: c#, silverlight, expression-blend, blend, sketchflow

I am using Sketchflow c# silverlight Expression Blend 4. I have a dragable control on a rectangle and I am trying to change the rectangle position in c# on mouse click. How can this be achieved? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to drag the rectangle around, make the parent of the control a canvas and then drag a MouseDragElementBehavior onto the control.

If you know what position you want it to move to and want it to work with just a click, you drag a ChangePropertyAction behavior onto it to set the margin property (or some other layout property).